# Incrementing data in JSON format

Tags: json

I have the below JSON request and need to multiply it for 100 users with unique email address and telephone number.

```
[
  {
    "externalKey": "01",
    "customerDetails": {
      "address": {
        "address": "A St",
        "country": "AU",
        "postcode": "3044",
        "state": "Victoria",
        "unitOrBuilding": "1"
      },
      "postalAddress": {
        "address": "A St",
        "country": "AU",
        "postcode": "3044",
        "state": "Victoria",
        "unitOrBuilding": "1"
      },
      "alternateEmailAddress": "",
      "dateOfBirth": "1990-10-31",
      "defaultProfileName": "QA System",
      "emailAddress": "**${Email}**",
      "familyName": "System",
      "personalName": "QA",
      "phoneNumberInternational": "**+${TelephoneNumber}**"
    },
     "ecardDetails": {
     "accountOrCardName": "Account Name",
     "accountOrCardNumber": "555555555",
     "bankNumber": "999888",
     "cardExpiry": "2020-01-01",
     "displayName": "Account Name",
     "isForWebPayments": false,
     "type": "BANKACCOUNT"
    }
  }
]
```

Test Intention:
I will then put all the 100 users in 1 HTTP request and will verify the time taken to register these users in the server.

Comment: What problem are you running into?  What language are you using? `"${Email}"` isn't json (unless it's a literal string).

Comment: Hi Chris.. Thanks for the message.. I am new to programming and don't have an idea on how to generate the outcome that I wanted.

Previously, I was creating 100 requests, 1 for each user and parameterised email and telephone. Now, I need to have all the requests in 1 API only.

Comment: To restate your intent, you have a request template, and want to substitute values for the template parameters. You then want to add the instantiated template into a collection.

Comment: @tehhowch : You are right... All the templates should be appended

Comment: Now that you have good names for what you are trying to do, please edit the post to include the code that you have tried to use to instantiate the template, e.g. ("I used javascript / php / c# / java .... with code loop < ... loop ... > and keep getting errors about < stuff >"). No one can help you if we do not know what you have tried and what you are working with.